# Rails Admin namespace and Admin Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a rails 4 application with an admin interface, so im trying to setup it under a Admin namespace for controllers and views, but have my models shared.

The think is that i have an Admin model and I want to know if this can cause any kind of problems.

On my routes I have

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :admins
    resources :categories 
end
```

my controllers are on

```
app/controllers/admin/something_controller.rb
```

for example:

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
```

My models are on
     app/models/model.rb

The thing is that one of the models is Admin, like:

```
 class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
```

So, I'm worried that when I do `class Admin::CategoriesController < ApplicationController` Im extending from my model Admin or something like that.

I dont have

```
module Admin
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `CategoriesController` inheriting from `ActionController::Base` like this:

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < ActionController::Base
```

Comment: I think she is asking whatever is possible to have Class Admin and Module Admin, or that wlil be an issue.